# What is the typical time to get the location on android?

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

I am using [react-native-location](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location) to get the location on android.

This package's installation documentation for android says:

> The library provides two methods of getting the location on Android.
>   The default is the builtin location manager, however, you can
>   optionally choose to install the Fused Location library which provides
>   more accurate and faster results.

I need to get the location on my app's startup, and decide based on that in which 'application mode' to start (each mode has a different home screen).
So, on one hand, getting the location is very important, but on the other hand I don't want the user to wait more than a fraction of a second.

My code for getting the location is:

```
RNLocation.configure({ distanceFilter: 0,
      desiredAccuracy: 'highAccuracy' });
    RNLocation.getLatestLocation({ timeout: xxx })
```

Based on your experience: how long will it usually take to get the location with and without the Fused Location library?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try the code bellow:

```
import GetLocation from 'react-native-get-location'

GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 15000,
})
.then(location => {
    console.log(location);
})
.catch(error => {
    const { code, message } = error;
   console.warn(code, message);
})
```

enableHighAccuracy: Set true to use 'fine location' (GPS) our false to use 'course location' (Wifi, Bluetooth, 3G).

timeout: The max time (in milliseconds) that you want to wait to receive a location.

if you usuning android pay attetion to this:

> !-- Define ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION if you will use enableHighAccuracy=true  -->
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
>
> !-- Define ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION if you will use enableHighAccuracy=false  -->
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>